# How to roughly analyze computational complexity of quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-circuit, complexity-theory

I'm looking for just a few simple calculations to analyze complexity when comparing quantum circuits.

I'll compare 2 scenarios, and I'd love for someone to critique or verify my analysis:

1. Circuit of width "n", and one multi-qubit gate that involves all "n" of the qubits.  (e.g. a MCT gate, in which the target qubit is an ancilla).
2. Circuit also of width "n", but with a single qubit gate on each of the "n" wires.  (e.g. a simple NOT gate)

Comparing the complexities of the above:

1. Tensor product of "n" qubits, so in worst case $O(2^n)$.
2. $O(2)$ for each single qubit gate, so in worse case $O(2n)$.

Therefore, for the same computation time, I can apply $\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}$ layers of circuit 2) instead of applying circuit 1).  Is this correct?

I realize there are a few questions out there about this, but the ultimate goal is to compare whether decompositions of MCT will provide any benefit (and if so under what scenarios).

Comment: When you say "complexity", what do you mean exactly? Is your definition of complexity considering 1) the computational time needed to classically simulate the quantum circuit, 2) the number of gates in the quantum circuit, 3) the number of **native** gates in the quantum circuit? Also related, you should probably revise your usage of the big-O notation here, that does not seem adequate (or I misunderstood something).

Comment: Number 1).  The computational time needed to classically simulate the quantum circuit.  

Can you elaborate just a little on what you mean?  I'm happy to edit the question if you help me understand a bit what specifically seems inadequate.

Comment: Ok for 1). For the big-O remark, after re-reading your question, I misunderstood it sorry. I think I got it now.

Comment: I haven't really gotten any conclusion on this but I'm hoping someone can either confirm/refute my understanding.